# How to handle running into CORS error codes

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, cors

Problem:

- I send a CORS request [edit: **improperly-executed**]
- The server receives the request and attempts to process it.
- The server returns an error response, for example a `422 Unprocessable Entity`, along with JSON information about the errors.  The idea is that my app could receive this error information and handle it appropriately in the UI.
- The browser blocks my error handler from getting the response content, or even getting the status code.

Showing that the browser received the `401` status code but treated it as a CORS security error:

[image: Status Code 401]

The response object, showing that my code cannot access the response data (`data: ""`, `status: 0`):

[image: Obscured Response Object]

Confusingly, when the server responds with a success code, the browser processes it as expected, and my client code receives the response.

How have other people handled this limitation?  My best guess right now is to hijack an HTTP "success" code (`2XX`) as an error code, and then include the error information in the response.  This prevents me from using the ajax error handlers in a normal way, but I'm handling this as a global ajax filter anyway, so this filter would capture the deviant success code and trigger the error handlers instead.

Comment: that link does have another answer on it, btw.  I can't tell if you're trying to fix the error or simply catch it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The console message indicates that the server isn't sending the required `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header when it sends the 401 response code.

You won't be able to use the CORS error handler to inject content into the DOM unless you fix that.

The server is likely sending the header correctly on responses with a 200 response code. It needs to do it for other response codes, though, if you wish to use data from those response codes.

Fix that on the server end before making design compromises on the client side. That may solve your problem straight away.

Comment: The server is sending the necessary headers on success. It needs to send them on failure too.

Comment: In other words, you need to send the CORS header on response codes other than 200 if you wish to use the JSON data from response codes other than 200.

Answer (score -1):

It seems it's an opaque response where you can't obtain the headers or the response. And everything is set to null or empty.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/type

Or maybe in the server you should add:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Answer (score -1):

Very late answer but in case someone wants to check whether an error occurred while sending an `XMLHttpRequest` and then take appropriate actions (on the CLIENT side), then this is a quick workaround:

```
try{
    request.send();
}catch(err){
    if(e.toString().startsWith("NetworkError")){
        //pasre the string to check error code
        //and take appropriate actions
    }
}
```

This is needed because the `onreadystatechange` function doesn't get executed when a `NetworkError` occurs and, in fact, the whole script is terminated.

Comment: Is this specific to CORS, or any XHR?

Comment: @colllin I'm not sure but anything that shows a `NetworkError` in the console can be handled in this manner.