# Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy:

Tags: next.js, cors, ipfs, ipfs-http-client

I am getting this Browser Error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://infura-ipfs.io/ipfs/Qmdet.....pE1A' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I think the problem is to get the data from infura?

Already tried do add a header.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26695017/how-to-handle-cors-error-code

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-the-access-control-allow-origin-header-work?rq=1